# VB6 Maximum Size of an Array

Tags: vb6

Dear StackOverflow USers!

I recently came across an unusual need to solve a problem in VB6. I have developed an application where I need to temporarily store very large volumes of data into the memory. Since classes and class members talke up more resources and more important need more time to unload, I came across the idea to use arrays. However is seems not to be possible to use all the available RAM on my computer. Could anyone give me an idea of how I could solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, and in my case it wasnt worth the effort to split the data in multiple smaller arrays, because it would require a huge code re-write. Maybe in your case its much simpeler. At least I can confirm that the max size of an array is much smaller than the available RAM in the machine. That is not weird, because the memory manager must find a continous block of free memory, which are rare. But VB6 seems to have an additional artifical limit.

Comment: Could you write your data to a file (maybe xml, csv, or something) rather than create an array?

Comment: Unfortunately writing the data to a file won't work, because I need to process the information contained by the array. And this is much faster in memory than on the disk...

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that a VB6 array can store as much memory as VB6 can address: 2GB. (or is it 4GB?)  AFAIK, there's no 64bit version of VB6.  If you need more, just upgrade to VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "all the RAM on your computer". If you are using the VB6 compiler, being 32-bit, you are only ever going to be able to use 2G of RAM as standard, because that is the maximum amount of memory that VB6 can address at a time. It may be  possible to hack the executable to take advantage of 3G on a /3G windows or Win64 machine using EDITBIN.EXE, but I would be surprised if it worked.

Your best bet is to write the data to a temporary file. You should use CreateFile() / ReadFile() WinAPI calls to do file access, because VB6 has the same 2G limitation on file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The array size limit in VB6 is the highest value of a signed 32-bit integer, or 2,147,483,647 elements.

That should actually be enough to cover the full address space for a 32-bit program, but this is unlikely to use the full RAM allocation of a modern computer running a 64-bit OS.

Had you considered writing this processing step in another language that supports a 64-bit address space, and just executing this program from within your VB6 program?

I actually ran into the same problem with VB3, which only permitted arrays 2^15-1 elements large, which was a real drag - just under 33,000 elements made memory sorting of many systems impractical.

Comment: Working on the issue I actuially came across a couple of quite interesing issues. For instance, when having let's say 15,000,000 fixed size String array, there is no problem to create it by Dim A(15000000) as String. However the real issue comes when populating the array. If the elements lengths are short enough there is no problem. But when they are close to 255 chars the program stops. If somebody could comment on that it would be great. Or shall I ask another question?

Comment: Strings in VB6 are structs - so the memory for them is not allocated when you  create an array to hold them. Instead what you get is an array of null pointers (They are a BSTR struct internally, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx) ; I think VB6 just equates a null string pointer with an empty string for convenience though. When you allocate strings, more memory will be consumed for BSTR structs.